# PHP generate 3 combination from array

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

**I will combine the following array:**
This array will be combined with itself

```
Array (

[0] => Array

    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 4
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
    )
);
```

**after combined will produce an array like this:**

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 4
    )

);
```

for example, from 1.2 combined with 1.3 will produce 1,2,3 or from 1,2 with 1,4 = 1,2,4

Comment: I've tried, but the result is too many and irregular. Thank you

Comment: making the combination

Comment: should it return only 3 nested items(as shown above) ?

Comment: Yes, Thanks if you answer

Comment: is there any logic on which part combines to which part? cannot deduce a logic from the input and output.

Comment: combine with next array. and if value same with previous value eliminated this

Comment: `1,2 + 1,3 = 123`, `1,2 + 1,4 = 124`, `1,2 + 2,3 = 234` ?? how

Comment: Yes like that. than kyou

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you want to like this. So you need to check condition which index array concatenate and that index don't check to push value

```
  $my_Arr = array( 

         array(1,2),
         array(1,3),
         array(1,4),
         array(2,3),
         array(2,4),
         array(3,4)
     );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_Arr);

echo "     -------------------------          <br> ";

  $elements  = sizeof($my_Arr);
  $first_num = '';
  $second_num = '';
  for ($i=0; $i < $elements; $i++) { 
      $subelements = sizeof($my_Arr[$i]);
      if($subelements < 4){
         for ($j=0; $j < $subelements ; $j++) { 

         if($j == 0 ){
               $first_num =$my_Arr[$i][$j];

         }

         if($j == 1 ){
             $second_num =$my_Arr[$i][$j];

         }

          if($first_num !=null && $second_num != null){

                for ($k=0; $k < $elements; $k++) { 
            for ($l=0; $l < $subelements ; $l++) { 
                if($first_num == $my_Arr[$k][$l] && $second_num!=$my_Arr[$k][$l+1]){

                    if (!in_array($my_Arr[$k][$l+1],$my_Arr[$i])) {
                        array_push($my_Arr[$i], $my_Arr[$k][$l+1]);
                    }

                   }
               }


              }

             }


          } 
       }

   }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_Arr);
```